# Where do 'apt-get' packages come from?

Tags: command-line, apt

So what I'm trying to ask is say I want to download Firefox. If I use 'sudo apt-get install firefox' does it get it from the Firefox website or some third-party repository?  Or is using 'apt-get install' the same as getting it from the website?

Comment: enter `apt-cache policy firefox` and you'll see where it'll come from.  Your sources provide where software will come from, and any priority rates given dictate if one is used over another.

Answer (score 1):

So most of the packages you'll get using `apt` will be from the official distributor/creator, excluding a package from a `ppa` (personal package archive). [Here is some info about apt](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apt.html.en). As @guiverc commented you can use `apt-cache policy <package>` to check where a package has come from, but also the version you have and the version you can update the package to using `apt`. If you want to make sure you're installing the latest version possible it's recommended to get the application from the provider's website. There's a vetting process for distributors to push their updates to the official apt repositories.

Comment: firefox:
  Installed: 65.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Candidate: 65.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 65.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     59.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages



Here is my output, does that mean Firefox comes from ubuntu?

Comment: If you installed it via `apt` it's coming from the ubuntu repositories. [65.0.2](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/) is the latest release.